# probability that 4 people will get their numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

4 women gave their coats to cloakroom. By the accident ruber mixed their number. He didn't say anything to women and gave them numbers. What probability is that women got they coats?

I thought that $P=1/4^4= 1/256$ but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Not quite!

There are 4•3•2•1 ways to give a number to each woman.

Only one of those assignments give each woman the correct coat.

Therefore, the probability is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{24}$

Comment: what about the probability that only one women will get her coat? is it 11/24? or 1/6?